# Using Rails Destroy Method without sending an http DELETE request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my `Website` model, my current method of letting users destroy an instance of that model is putting this on an html page:

```
<%= link_to "delete", website, :method => :delete %>
```

However, this would have to send a `DELETE` request to `/websites/:id(.:format)` in order to use the destroy method. I can't do that because the `id`'s of my `Websites` are strings such as `http://example.com`, meaning `localhost:3000/websites/http://example.com` just doesn't make sense.

So what I'm wondering is, is there another way to delete instances of my `Websites` model, other than sending an http `DELETE` request? I wish I could access the `destroy` method directly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have the primary key id's of the websites as integers, and then have a "url" string attribute that can be the `http://example.com` name.

This will make many things easier, notably associations. Also, you can still search for things based on the url, and you aren't really limited by making the url a column and an id # as the primary key.

Comment: the reason is because i have a model `Simulations` that needs to be associated with `Websites`, but they're added to my database through node.js
the only thing `Websites` and `Simulations` have in common is a `url` attribute. has a result, i have to manually map foreign keys.

Comment: this shouldn't stop you from using id's as a primary key instead of url's. If this is a throwaway app you're hacking together, it doesn't really matter, but if this is important, using the url as a primary key will be hellish to deal with in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure to understand your problem but have you take a look to [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/) ?

Thanks to this gem, you will be able to create url with string instead of basic sql primary ids.

Answer (score 0):

you can access public methods by adding new route to your routes.rb.

for example:

routes.rb

```
post '/websites/:id' => 'websites#destroy', :as => :destroy_website
```

view

```
<%= link_to "destroy", destroy_website_path(:id => "http://example.com"), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: can you explain some things though? what is the `:as` for? i get this error in my routes.rb file: `undefined local variable or method `destroy_website'`

Comment: it creates methods: destroy_website_path and destroy_website_url. There is no such a method destroy_website.

Comment: my bad it is not destroy_website, it is :destroy_website

Comment: what is _id?  I don't think that there is an attribute called _id

Comment: dang. you still get this error:
`No route matches [DELETE] "/websites/http://example.com"`

Comment: if your destroy action finds website like that @website = Website.find(params[:id]). it has to work!